# How to add a new chip so its nicely ordered and button shifting?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to add chips with new tags and they should be nicely ordered, so the next chip that follows should be right next to the first chip, the third should be after the second chip etc. At the same time the add-button should also shift to the right side, so it will always be right in front of the last chip that was created. Until now I only have the add a new chip function. I don't expect you to do the coding work just tell me how I could  do it or if you have code examples that you could copy. Because I haven't found any tutorials or yt videos online. My existing code is below.

HTML

```
<ion-chip #chip *ngFor="let tag of tagName">

  <ion-label>{{tag.tag}}</ion-label>
  <button ion-button clear color="dark" (click)="remove(chip)">
    <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-chip>

<button class="buttonIcon" ion-button small round icon-only (click)="add(chip)">  <!--When "add" button is pressed -> opens searchbar (not done yet)-->
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

TS

```
public tagName = [
    {
      "tag": "#men"

    },
  ];
…

 add(chip: Element) {
    this.tagName.push();

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it simple, use `push` to add and `splice` to remove. For adding you don't need any parameter for the method, but for removing, just pass the chip's id.

```
export class Tag {
  tag: string;
  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}

...
  tagName: Tag[] = [];

  add(): void {
    let id = this.tagName.length + 1;
    this.tagName.push(new Tag({ tag: "tag" + id }, ));
  }

 remove(id: number): void {
    this.tagName.splice(id, 1);
 }
```

HTML

```
   <ion-chip #chip *ngFor="let tag of tagName; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{tag.tag}}</ion-label>
        <button ion-button clear color="dark" (click)="remove(i)">
           <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
        </button>
  </ion-chip>


  <button class="buttonIcon" ion-button small round icon-only (click)="add(chip)">  
     <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tvy4wp)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your add button in ion-chip element and it will align in the right side

Try like this

**Html**

```
<ion-chip #chip *ngFor="let tag of tagName">

 <ion-label>{{tag.tag}}</ion-label>
  <button ion-button clear color="dark" (click)="remove(chip)">
    <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    </ion-chip>

    <ion-chip color="primary">
    <button ion-button clear color="light" (click)="add(chip)">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    </ion-chip>
```

you can refer the stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bcfc7y?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: Thx, for your answer. In my project I have the problem that new chips are just layed over the last chip not like in your Blitzdemo. And the add-button is also on the left side of the chip. Do u know why. I used exactly your code from Blitz.

Comment: do you added any styles to your page can you update the whole code in stackblitz